# Exception reading from H2 Database: The object is already closed

Tags: java, h2

I have a problem with my Database and prepareStatements.
I use H2, cause it's just a tutorial, and I can't understand why these tests don't work.

I get the org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-210

Here are tests, number four (testReadActualDB) throws this exception.
The line that causes problem is
PreparedStatement statement = **connector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);**

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("Create table in DB")
    @Order(1)
    public void testCreateTableDB() throws SQLException {
    String testQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(\n" +
            "     test_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
            "     name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL\n" +
            ")";

    PreparedStatement statement = сonnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(testQuery);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    statement.close();
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Write to DB")
@Order(2)
public void testWriteDB() throws SQLException {
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO test"
            + " (name) VALUES" + " (?)";

    PreparedStatement insertPreparedStatement = сonnector.getConnection()
            .prepareStatement(insertQuery);
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(1, "hello from JUnit");

    insertPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    insertPreparedStatement.close();
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Read from DB")
@Order(3)
public void testReadDB() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_id=?";

    PreparedStatement statement = сonnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setLong(1, 1);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        assertEquals(1, rs.getLong("test_id"));
        assertEquals("hello from JUnit", rs.getString("name"));
    }

    statement.close();

}

@Test
@DisplayName("Read data from DB")
@Order(4)
public void testReadActualDB() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM clan WHERE clan_id=?";

    PreparedStatement statement = **connector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);**
    statement.setLong(1, 1);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        assertEquals(1, rs.getLong("clan_id"));
        assertEquals("Elfs", rs.getString("name"));
    }

    statement.close();
}
```

Here's the stack trace for the exception:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-210]

```
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:573)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:227)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:203)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:192)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1372)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:286)
at DBTest.testReadActualDB(DBTest.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

However, when I combine these two tests in one method - everything works just fine:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Read from DB")
@Order(3)
public void testReadDB() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_id=?";

    PreparedStatement statement = сonnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setLong(1, 1);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        assertEquals(1, rs.getLong("test_id"));
        assertEquals("hello from JUnit", rs.getString("name"));
    }

    statement.close();

    sql = "SELECT * FROM clan WHERE clan_id=?";

    statement = сonnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setLong(1, 1);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        assertEquals(1, rs.getLong("clan_id"));
        assertEquals("Elfs", rs.getString("name"));
    }

    statement.close();

}
```

Here's my Connector class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class H2Connector {

    private final String jdbcURL = "jdbc:h2:~/test";
    private final String jdbcUser = "sa";
    private final String jdbcPass = "";

    @SneakyThrows
    public Connection getConnection() {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUser, jdbcPass);

        return connection;
    }
}
```

That's how I add H2 to the project (fragment from pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.210</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't see what I'm missing. Can anyone help me, please? :)

P.S.: When I add console output just before the problematic line, everything starts working

```
System.out.println(connector.getConnection().isClosed() + " ");
PreparedStatement statement = connector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
```

It prints "true" to the console and then just goes on and passes the test.